# Where can I download Autofac.dll 3.4.0.0 without Nuget?

Tags: autofac

I need autofac.dll 3.4.0.0 but I cannot find it.
One of our project used to run properly with a previous version but it seems that there were an update on our server...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can "download" any package and use the contents using the NuGet command line. Just open a command prompt in an empty folder and use:

```
nuget install Autofac -Version 3.4.0
```

It'll "install" the package in the empty folder and you can go into the "lib" folder and pull the assembly out if you need.

Answer (score -1):

I have found an autofac.dll with version 3.4.1.0 and the project now runs fine again, even if the error message was saying that a version 3.4.0.0 was needed...